# Error in load Properties file and upload image in jboss 7 server

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

In jeety , Glassfish server when project is deploy then make one folder in webapp but in jboss 7 server have no webapp folder.

where is project deploy( folder name ) in jboss 7?

so there are some problem like read properties file and image upload . b'caz i use class path and server path for it.

for ex in jboss 7:
get File path : "E:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/mwp.war/WEB-INF/classes/analytics.properties"

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
String fileName = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("analytics.properties").getFile();
pro.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName),null);
```

then get error :

```
16:21:52,004 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
16:21:52,006 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
16:21:52,007 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
16:21:52,008 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at mwp.slktechlabs.model.analytics.AnalyticsDBData.updateAnalyticsPropertiesData(AnalyticsDBData.ja
va:95)
16:21:52,010 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:21:52,011 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
16:21:52,013 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:21:52,015 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
16:21:52,016 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleEle
ment.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340)
16:21:52,018 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMet
adata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
16:21:52,020 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessB
eforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:148)
16:21:52,023 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.ja
va:166)
16:21:52,025 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingle
tonBeanRegistry.java:487)
16:21:52,027 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultS
ingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
16:21:52,029 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(Default
SingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
16:21:52,031 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationC
ontext.java:1053)
16:21:52,033 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContex
t.java:463)
16:21:52,035 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294
)
16:21:52,036 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215)
16:21:52,038 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.j
ava:47)
16:21:52,040 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)
16:21:52,041 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)
16:21:52,043 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
16:21:52,045 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:18
11)
16:21:52,046 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
16:21:52,048 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
16:21:52,050 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
16:21:52,051 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

so how to remove this error ?

Thanks,
kamlesh

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "path" );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf8"));
prop.load(br);
```

example in my war i have got properties ingo resources/config/myprop.properties and my "path" is config/myprop.properties

Jboss as 7 have got few deploy folder if you using hot deeploy (run only with standalone mode)
jboss deploy your project in example: /usr/local/jboss7/standalone/deployments
example you can put in this place war file and jboss automaticly deploy your project

but if you using mavej jboss pluging and use command jboss-as:deploy so jboss deploy your project into  /usr/local/jboss7/standalone/data/content